# what is the difference between empty() and $_POST["name"]==""; in php?

Tags: php

i couldn't figured it out what is the real difference functionality between `empty()` and `$_POST["xxx"]==""`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`empty()`](http://php.net/empty) is a statement (unlike any function you could define) which will not trigger an E_NOTICE if called on a variable that is actually undefined. So it also include an [`isset`](http://php.net/isset) check.

> Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE. empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist.

Note that "equals FALSE" means an `==` comparison, so e.g. empty strings, a string containing a single zero, NULL, empty arrays are all considered empty.

Comment: It should also be noted that the `isset()` call will mean that it cannot be `NULL` either. @skobaljic That would cause an `E_NOTICE`, though.

Comment: Wouldn't `null == false` also be true?

Comment: also `empty()` checks for `"" (an empty string)`
`0 (0 as an integer)`
`0.0 (0 as a float)`
`"0" (0 as a string)`
`NULL`
`FALSE`
`array() (an empty array)`
`$var; (a variable declared, but without a value)`

Comment: This one is correct you said: `var_dump( false == null );     #bool(true)`

Answer (score 0):

### The following things are considered to be empty `(return true)`:

> "" (an empty string)
>
> 0 (0 as an integer)
>
> 0.0 (0 as a float)
>
> "0" (0 as a string)
>
> NULL
>
> FALSE
>
> array() (an empty array)
>
> $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)

**BUT**

> $_POST["xxx"]==""

Return true when $_POST["xxx"] is an empty string